# Screen Size Resolution problem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I have Some Background image in to My Application. That background Image also contain the Button image. I am manualy create and set the Button on that Button image of the Background Image. now while the Screeen size changes for another device then the real button and the Button Image that show on the Background image shows different. How i can set it for the ProperView. Or if i want to make another Background Image that dont contain the Image of the Button. Then which Screen size should i have to prefer for different Device Competibility.
I have read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html) competibility documents. But not getting proper idea if i have to set the background image for all device then which screen size i have to prefer. So can any budy explain me in Short and Sweet ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), you have to create multiple layout folders!

For example: you can have 2 versions of **my_layout.xml**

1. res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml
2. res/layout-normal/my_layout.xml

Read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html); There are lots of details there.

Comment: Ok Thanks for reply. Now i got the point. But there are no any directory in my project as like layout-xlarge and layout-normal. So Should i have to made it with my own way or any steps are there to make that directory. . .?

Comment: How to make this directory ? Should i have to make it manualy or there is any option in Eclipse to make it ?

Answer (score 0):

[Read Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html); There are lots of details there.